# Formik `isSubmitting` and `isValidating` are `false` during pre-submit validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I'm submitting a form using Formik. I want to have slightly different validation logic depending on whether it's being triggered by blur/change events or pre-submit validation. (Long story short, during pre-submit, I only want to run sync validation — my back end will do the same async validation that I run on blur/change when I submit the form, so I want to skip it in pre-submit.) My validate function looks something like this:

```
  validate={(value) => {
    const error = validateSync(value);
    if (!error && !form.isSubmitting) {
      return validateAsync(value);
    }
    return error;
  }}
```

In this case, I'm using `useFormikContext` to get `form.isSubmitting`.

According to the [Formik docs](https://formik.org/docs/guides/form-submission) on submission, `isSubmitting` should be set to `true` immediately in the **Pre-submit** stage, before the **Validation** stage. This doesn't seem to be happening, as you can see if you try to submit the form in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-1jgkw?file=/index.js:1407-1419) (check the console to see that both `isSubmitting` and `isValidating` are `false` — according to the Formik docs, they should both be `true` at this stage).

Another user had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774988/formik-validation-issubmitting-isvalidating-not-getting-set-to-true/64818271), but the answer doesn't address the underlying (possible) bug with Formik.

Answer (score 0):

Used React's useRef hook to reference the current version of the form:

```
const form = useFormikContext();
const formRef = useRef();
formRef.current = form;

// within a delayed callback:
function delayedCallback() {
  // pulls the current value of isSubmitting, whenever the delayedCallback fires
  const { isSubmitting } = formRef.current;
};
```

Works 100%